Custom Logging In WCF service
I have a WCF project that has an exposed API. I want to log requests and responses from my server. I have adjusted the web.config file to do some logging via the system.diagnostics section in the config. I was able to get the logs to begin logging however I would like to be able to more customly log. I've been looking around and have found that I can make new classes that implement IEndpointBehavior, BehaviorExtensionElement, IDispatchMessageInspector although I haven't been able to get it log and not stop calls to the API from working (being processed). I'm still quite confused based on microsoft's documentation. Could someone give me an explanation of how to use the provided class extensions to create logging that will log requests and response of a specific operation contracts (GetRateLandedCost(RateRequest request) & ShipParcel(routingDeliveryRequest request)) that have certain body values (Both RateRequest and RoutingDeliveryRequest have an "AccountNumber" field for filtering)?
Here are my current configs for the basic logging I've already implemented:
        <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
        <messageLogging
            logEntireMessage="true"
            logMalformedMessages="true"
            logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
            logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
            maxMessagesToLog="5000"
            maxSizeOfMessageToLog="5000000" />
    </diagnostics>

        <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="messages"
                    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                    initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>

I have tried to create classes that extend the logging. I've tried to create classes that extend IEndpointBehavior, BehaviorExtensionElement, IDispatchMessageInspector although they have made calls to the API break. I've looked over the documentation although I'm still confused on how to actually implement this and what modifications need to be made to the config; I've tried adding endpoint behavior extensions. I expected this to create a file on the server that consisted of logs from a specific endpoint which had a specific value in its body.

In general, our steps are:
Create a custom message inspector: Implement the IDispatchMessageInspector interface to intercept and log request and response messages.
Create a custom behavior: Implement the IEndpointBehavior interface and apply a custom message inspector to it.
Extension Configuration: Create a custom behavior extension via BehaviorExtensionElement to configure custom behaviors in web.config.
Configure web.config: Add custom behavior to the service's configuration.

But I tried to do this, and at the end the addition of the web.config file never got the new method I inherited and the log could not be generated. How far have you got, are you having the same problem as me, and I hope my problem will be solved.
